# Exclude table from amazon RDS multi az secondary DB sync

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've got an amazon RDS postgres database, with the multi AZ option enabled.

There is a table with an extremely intense number of writes, but with very volatile information. If the information was lost, it wouldn't be a high damage (assuming this is happening almost never).

Is it possible to exclude the sincronization of this table among the main an the secondary database? So if there was a problem with the main database, when the secondary is promoted to be the main, this table would be empty. The idea is to reduce the cost of sincronization.

Comment: Which "cost of synchronization" are you referring to?  Is there a cost of synchronization?

Comment: Just in case the synchronization affected the performance of the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon RDS's Multi-AZ feature works at the instance-level only. It's not possible to selectively sync at the database level or the table level.

If this is a big concern, you could separate such tables onto a different RDS instance that is not Multi-AZ.